# Gitlab-Runner diff command not working with russian name of files

Tags: git, unicode, diff, gitlab-ci, jobs

```
Running with gitlab-runner 12.1.0 (de7731dd)
on Zhanar KRRaWTmf
Using Shell executor... 

$ git archive -o update.zip HEAD $(git diff --name-only HEAD^)

fatal: pathspec '╨Ц╨░╨╜╨░╤А.txt' did not match any files

ERROR: Job failed: exit status 1
```

Comment: It's very much recommended to store everything in Git in UTF-8 encoding. Your files seems to be in koi8-r or cp866 encoding.

Comment: Thanks for your recommend, i am realy trying, but nothing help me, so if to set cp1251 on shell and linux lang config it's helps?